# load text file with button with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to load a text file with button. Without button it works. But with button it doesn' t.

I have this:

```
$("#lesen").click(function () {
jQuery.get('movie.txt', function (data) {

        var lines = data.split("\n");

        $.each(lines, function (n, elem) {
            $('#content_area').append('<div>' + elem + '</div>');
        });

    });
});
```

and this is the html file:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <script type ="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/JFunc.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>


      <input type="button" id="lessen" value="load"  />
    <div id="content_area"></div>
      </div>

    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

I have it now like this:

```
$("#lessen").click(function () {
    alert('lsdjflkjsdf');
jQuery.get('movie.txt', function (data) {

        var lines = data.split("\n");

        $.each(lines, function (n, elem) {
            $('#content_area').append('<div>' + elem + '</div>');
        });

    });
});
```

but I even dont see the alert, when I activate the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a typo, your button `id` is `lessen` and your jQuery selector refers to `#lesen`:

```
$("#lesen").click(function () {
```

Try this:

```
$("#lessen").click(function () {
```

And to make sure the DOM is loaded before the script is executed, you should pass it as a callback to `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#lessen").click(function () {
    alert('lsdjflkjsdf');
    jQuery.get('movie.txt', function (data) {
      var lines = data.split("\n");
      $.each(lines, function (n, elem) {
        $('#content_area').append('<div>' + elem + '</div>');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That was it!!

Answer (score 1):

You should write the same id names in both the files at every place you refer.

```
$("#lesen").click(function () {.....
```

Replace the above line with the below snippet in your jQuery code

```
$("#lessen").click(function () {.....
```

Actually you misspelt the id name **#lessen** in your JavaScript file @ line 1

Answer (score 0):

use this  id = "lessen ".

```
$("#lessen").click(function () {
  //Your code hare . 
}
```